# Stuck on purple loading screen

Tags: reboot

I just downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 today. It was running slow, so I tried the Enlightenment E17 Desktop. I didn't like it and was getting an error message when trying to use the software manager, so I was going to restart and go back to the original. When I restarted, I got stuck on the purple Ubuntu loading screen. The terminal still works (Ctrl+Alt+F2), but nothing happens on the screen. I'm using a HP Compaq dc5700 Microtower  Intel Pentium D, 1 G of RAM. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

On the Grub2 boot selection screen press "e".

Add the following to the end of the string (you may want to write this down)

```
noapic nolapic acpi=off
```

Comment: I just reinstalled it. Thank you for your suggestion!